# Error ITMS : 90524 UIDeviceFamily Error

Tags: ios

I am getting this error when uploading build on appstore. Can anyone provide me solutions for this.

Help will be appreciated.

Error is :

**ERROR ITMS-90524**: "Invalid UIDeviceFamily. The Info.plist of Apple Watch application 'path/TodoWidget.app' contains an invalid UIDeviceFamily value of '2'."

Comment: In Targeted Device Family its shows value : 1,2

Comment: That is for iPhone & iPad.  This is fine for your base app but not for a watch target.  It must be 4 for a watch app or extension

Comment: How to add that 4 in target family because in there drop down there will be only 3 option [1] , [2] , [1,2]

Comment: How did you create your watch target?  Xcode should set the right value for you when you create the watch app target.

Comment: Actually i m just choose that watch os target and deployment version.

Comment: Ok now i solved this my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check out your as given below

just right click on .xcodeproj file and then choose show package contents - >  now there will be project.pbxproj file opened it.
and then set the targeted device family “1,2” in target.

Now save this and open your project.

Its working fine :)

Comment: My device family is already set to "1,2" but still get this warning. Any lead on that?

Comment: I noticed that if I change build number from the .xcarchive file or .app file and upload the app to the appstore, then this warning shows up. Although the device family is correct.